# Generate .xlsx file in custom specified format

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any possibility to generate `.xlsx` file in custom specified format using HTML,CSS in Jquery/Javascript/Rails,format is look like this

[image]

Comment: A goog starting point for ruby is the [axlsx-gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this gem for generating excel with rails [xlsx generation with charts, images, automated column width, customizable styles and full schema validation](https://github.com/randym/axlsx)

for sample example,[sample example syntaxes](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb)  check in this link

The following sample code for generating excel format as specified above as you experted

```
def excel 

@package = Axlsx::Package.new

@wb = @package.workbook
load_styles #----> to call load_styles function for styles
 @wb.add_worksheet name: 'outline_level', fit_to_page: true do |sheet|
 sheet.add_row [""],:height => 6   
 sheet.add_row ["","","","","","","",""],:height => 20, :b => true, :style => @align_center
 sheet.merge_cells("A2:H2") 
 sheet.add_row [""],:height => 6

 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""], :sz => 10, :style => @top,:height => 16,:style => @top_right
 sheet.merge_cells("A4:D4") 
 sheet.merge_cells("F4:H4")
 sheet.rows.last.cells[5].b = true


 @exporter = @invoice.exporter_address.split("\n")
 @importer = @invoice.plant_address.split("\n")
 @consignee = @invoice.consignee_address.split("\n")
 @notifyparty = @invoice.clearingagent_address.split("\n")

 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""], :sz => 10,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A5:D5") 
 sheet.merge_cells("F5:H5") 
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].sz = 8
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true

 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""], :sz => 10,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A6:D6") 
 sheet.merge_cells("E6:H6")
 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].sz = 8
 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].b = true
  sheet.rows.last.cells[0].sz = 8
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].style = @top




 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "#{}", "","",""], :sz => 9,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A7:D7") 
 sheet.merge_cells("E7:H7")
  sheet.rows.last.cells[4].b = true
   sheet.rows.last.cells[4].style = @align_center
  sheet.rows.last.cells[0].sz = 8
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true


 sheet.add_row ["","","","","","","",""],:height => 10
 sheet.merge_cells("A8:D8")
 sheet.merge_cells("E8:H8")
 sheet.rows.last.cells[3].style = @right
  sheet.rows.last.cells[7].style = @right

 sheet.add_row ["","","","", "", "","",""], :sz => 8,:height => 12,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A9:D9")
 sheet.merge_cells("E9:H9")


 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A10:D10")
 sheet.merge_cells("E10:H10")


 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].sz = 8

 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A11:D11")
 sheet.merge_cells("E11:H11")


 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true


 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A12:D12")
 sheet.merge_cells("E12:H12")


 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true


 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", "", "","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A13:D13")
 sheet.merge_cells("E13:H13")


 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true



 sheet.add_row ["","","","","","","",""],:height => 0,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A15:D15")
 sheet.merge_cells("E15:H15")
  sheet.rows.last.cells[3].style = @right
  sheet.rows.last.cells[7].style = @right



 sheet.add_row ["", "","","", " ", "","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @top_right
 sheet.merge_cells("A16:D16")
 sheet.merge_cells("E16:H16")

 sheet.add_row ["","","","","","","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 12,:style => @top_right
 sheet.merge_cells("A23:B23")
 sheet.merge_cells("C23:D23")
 sheet.merge_cells("E23:H23")



 sheet.add_row ["","","","","","","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A24:B24") 
 sheet.merge_cells("C24:D24")
 sheet.merge_cells("E24:H24")
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[2].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[4].style = @align_center
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].style = @bottom_center
 sheet.rows.last.cells[2].style = @bottom_center


 sheet.add_row [" ","","","","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 12,:style => @right
 sheet.merge_cells("A25:B25")
 sheet.merge_cells("C25:D25")
 sheet.merge_cells("E25:H25")


 sheet.add_row ["","","#{@invoice.delivery_type}, #{@invoice.final_destination}","","","","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 16, :style => @bottom,:style => @right

 sheet.merge_cells("A26:B26")
 sheet.merge_cells("C26:D26")
 sheet.merge_cells("E26:H26")
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[2].b = true
 sheet.rows.last.cells[0].style = @align_center
 sheet.rows.last.cells[2].style = @align_center


 sheet.add_row [""," "," ","","","","",""],:sz => 8,:height => 12,:style => @top
 sheet.rows.last.cells[7].style = @center_right_top_border
  sheet.rows.last.cells[5].style = @right_left_border_top
  sheet.rows.last.cells[6].style = @right_left_border_top
 sheet.merge_cells("C27:E27")


  sheet.column_widths 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5


  end

   @package.serialize("#{Rails.root}/tmp/basic.xlsx")
     send_file("#{Rails.root}/tmp/basic.xlsx", filename: "excel.xlsx", type: "application/xlsx")

 end




 def load_styles
@wb.styles do |s|   
  @top = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :font_name => 'Arial',:border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:top] }
  @right = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:right] }
  @left = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:left] }
  @bottom = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:bottom] }
   @center = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :alignment => { :horizontal => :center }
  @top_bottom = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:top,:bottom] }
  @bold = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :b => true
   @top_right = s.add_style :font_name => 'Arial', :border => { :style => :thin, :color =>"00000000", :edges => [:top,:right] }
  end
 end
```